Manga where the female lead raises someone(?) then dies, reincarnates and meets them again
All I remember is one of the pages where she (the female lead, reincarnated) bumps into a person she raised and one she knew well, who then proceed to take her to a fancy café where the 2 people begin to question her with cold looks in their eyes around a round table,  upon which the female lead snaps and slams her hands into the table then stands up and shouts something along the lines of "I didn't raise you to be like this".
It's kind of an isekai, but also kinda not; I don't think the female lead was a person from Earth first before coming to that world then dying and being reincarnated in the same world immediately after, but as someone else.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How did the person she raised recognize her post-reincarnation?  Wouldn't she be much younger?  Also, where and when did you read this?

She was recognized because she started yelling about how she didn't raise him to be such a cold and unloving person unlike what he was before, all this happned around said round table in the caffé.
as for when i read it it would've been around 2 years ago, don't remember where

I want to say In The Land of Leadale but I'm not in a good spot to try to find the scene in the anime adaptation.

Okay, found what I was looking for. "I should have raised her better", but the rest of the scene doesn't really fit - it's in an office, spoken to the husband of the isekai'ed MC's foster daughter.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Could be "Charlotte Has Five Disciples"
